# scala parsing with nested parens

Tags: parsing, scala

Trying to parse an nested expressions like GroupParser.parse("{{a}{{c}{d}}}")
After many hours i have now following snipplet that parse {a} well, but fails with

```
[1.5] failure: ``}'' expected but `{' found  
{{a}{{b}{c}}}
    ^

sealed abstract class Expr

case class ValueNode(value:String) extends Expr

object GroupParser extends StandardTokenParsers {
    lexical.delimiters ++= List("{","}")

    def vstring = ident ^^ { case s => ValueNode(s) }   
    def expr = ( vstring | parens ) 
    def parens:Parser[Expr] = "{" ~> expr  <~ "}"

    def parse(s:String) = {
        val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(s)
        phrase(expr)(tokens)
    }

}
```

any hints?

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't nesting, it's sequencing.  Your grammar would allow arbitrary nesting of expressions inside curlies, but doesn't say that an expression can be sequenced so the parser can't handle {a} followed immediately by {{b}{c}}.  You can code sequencing using explicit recursion in your grammar or by using one of the rep variants in http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.html

Answer (score 1):

Can expressions be repeated multiple times? If so, this would work:

```
def expr = ( vstring | parens )+
```

However, it is not clear what is your grammar, or why would your example be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This parses the two examples you gave:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._

sealed abstract class Expr

case class ValueNode(value:String) extends Expr

case class ValueListNode(value:List[Expr]) extends Expr

object GroupParser extends StandardTokenParsers {
  lexical.delimiters ++= List("{","}")

  def vstring = ident ^^ { case s => ValueNode(s) }   
  def parens:Parser[Expr] = "{" ~> ( expr )  <~ "}"
  def expr = vstring | parens

  def exprList:Parser[Expr] = "{" ~> rep1( expr | exprList ) <~ "}" ^^ {
    case l => {
      ValueListNode(l)
    }
  }

  def anyExpr = expr | exprList

  def parse(s:String) = {
    val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(s)
    phrase(anyExpr)(tokens)
  }

  def test(s: String) = {
    parse(s) match {
      case Success(tree, _) =>
        println("Tree: " + tree)
      case e: NoSuccess => Console.err.println(e)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    test("{a}")
    test("{{a}}")
    test("{{a}{{b}{c}}}")
  }
}
```

And succeeds with output:

```
Tree: ValueNode(a)
Tree: ValueNode(a)
Tree: ValueListNode(List(ValueNode(a), ValueListNode(List(ValueNode(b), ValueNode(c)))))
```